# What is the difference between converting PNG images to JPEG using convertio.co

Tags: png, converters, jpeg, libjpeg

I have a small project that displays JPEG images on an external device. Images converted from the website convertio.co can be transmitted and displayed on the device, but when I try to convert original PNG images to JPEG using code, they cannot be displayed. Therefore, I want to know how the website converts images.

Could someone show me how, suggest ideas, or let me know what I need to learn in order to handle this? For example, using bytes, etc.

I understand that JPEG is lossy compression, but convertio compresses a PNG file size: 11.7 KB (11,996 bytes) into a JPEG size of 11.1 KB (11,376 bytes), while I've been trying to compress it without success, either ending up with a larger or smaller size.

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and [ask]. Then click [edit] and make sure you include the original PNG, the JPEG that works and the JPEG that doesn't work along with your conversion code. Thank you.